# What can be done to avoid Computation timed out for large area reduceRegion?

Tags: google-earth-engine, big-data

The reduceRegion below returns the value of the computation after a bit of waiting.

```js
var largeRegionReduced = ee.Image.constant(0).eq(ee.Image.constant(1)).selfMask()
                           .reduceRegion({
                             "reducer": ee.Reducer.count(),
                             "geometry": ee.Geometry.Point(74.52, 41.48).buffer(2500000).bounds(),
                             "scale": 30,
                             "crs": "EPSG:4326",
                             "maxPixels": 10000000000000})
                           .get("constant");
print(largeRegionReduced)
```

The same reduceRegion above, but with a buffer of 2800000, instead of 2500000, returns `Computation timed out!`

The code above is obviously the minimum self-contained piece of code. In the real code, the image to reduce, the scale, and the geometry, wouldn't be constant. I need to do this operation, possibly on even larger areas. What can I do?

Options already considered, which are not of interest:

1. Tile the area and combine results

- reasonable, but I would rather try anything else before

2. Use `bestEffort = True` parameter

- reasonable, but the result will be an approximation, and for my purpose only the exact result matters

3. Use the new Google Earth Engine projects, where I can probably create my own project that allows for more computing time

- reasonable, but unacceptable, given the constraints I have.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to export your result. When you print the value, Code Editor gets only 5 minutes to show you the result or it will time out. When you export, you have a larger pool of resources and longer time to compute your value.

Read this https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging?hl=en#timed-out